# Linux permissions

Tags: linux, permissions

*I know there are a lot of these out there already, but I still can't find the answer to the following.*

---

### Resources

- I have two users

  - `erik`
  - `www-data`
- I have one file

  - `/home/erik/foo.yaml`

---

### List groups

```shell
erik@erik:~$ groups erik
erik : erik www-data # ... and other irrelevant groups
erik@erik:~$ groups www-data
www-data : www-data erik
```

---

### List permissions

```shell
erik@erik:~$ ls -lhd foo.yaml
-rwxrwx--- 1 www-data www-data 216 jan  4 15:43 foo.yaml
```

---

### Permission denied

```shell
erik@erik:~$ echo "foo" > foo.yaml 
bash: foo.yaml: Permission denied
erik@erik:~$ cat foo.yaml 
cat: foo.yaml: Permission denied
```

---

### ID output

```shell
erik@erik:~$ id
uid=1000(erik) gid=1000(erik) grupper=1000(erik) # ... other irrelevant groups
```

---

### Question

Why do I get permission denied here?

Comment: I am not sure about this, but if you just added erik to www-data, you will need to log out and log back in.

Comment: Have you done `newgrp` in the shell to apply group changes?

Comment: I will try loggin in and out as thet problably is the aswer. Will update the question with id output..

Comment: @Pavan: Pls. make your comment an "offical" answer... :)

Comment: @Mörre: +1, waitng for this to

Comment: @ErikLandvall Added as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you add a new user to a group, you will need to log out and log back in to get access to the group permissions. Alternatively [newgrp](http://linux.die.net/man/1/newgrp) can do the same within the local environment.

Answer (score 0):

```
erik@ubuntu-vm:~$ groups erik
erik : erik www-data
erik@ubuntu-vm:~$ groups www-data
www-data : www-data erik
erik@ubuntu-vm:~$ ls -l /tmp/foo.yaml 
-rwxrwx--- 1 www-data www-data 3 Jan  4 18:49 /tmp/foo.yaml
erik@ubuntu-vm:~$ echo "Hi" > /tmp/foo.yaml 
erik@ubuntu-vm:~$ cat /tmp/foo.yaml 
Hi
```

I think you have some attributes on file. Can you paste the output of following command:

```
lsattr /path/to/file
```

Comment: Pavan alredy gave me the correct answer here. All I needed was to log in ond out..

Answer (score -1):

-rwxrwx--- 1 www-data www-data 216 jan  4 15:43 foo.yaml

Here owner of this file is 'www-data' and your are logged as 'erik' ,due to this denied permission problem is coming.Try change the file ownership using command 'chown username somefile '. or you can use sudo command like 'sudo echo "foo" > foo.yaml'

Comment: Someone didn't bother reading the question. Not to mention that by reading the existing comments you would have noticed it has been answered.